# only check SAML authenticated, do not forward

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I am using the spring-security-saml2 library to authenticate my user against a SAML IdP. It works well, but now I would like to only CHECK if a user is authenticated with that IdP (and avoid an automatic forward to ask the user for credentials).

The use case is that I want to add other custom authentication mechanisms, and only forward to a login page once ALL mechanisms failed. So I'd like to check for an active SAML session, if not then check via OAuth, ..., if not authenticated anywhere then forward the user to a login page.

Is this possible with the spring-security-saml2 library as it is or would I have to fork / change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can syncronize SAML sessions http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf.
But will be easier if you make your own session (with a small timeout and you reset the timeout each request) after your get redirected from the idp (auhtn request response success)

Comment: not sure we are talking about the same thing? I want to simply check if there is a SAML Session (without the user being automatically forwarded to log in with the IdP in case there is none).

Answer (score 0):

One can add the `isPassive` attribute to a SAML Authentication Request to obtain the behaviour that you're looking for. This is controlled by calling `setPassive(true)` on the `WebSSOProfileOptions` object, as shown in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/saml/websso/WebSSOProfileHoKImplTest.java#L263.